# Using an object as a value of a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Currently, I'm coding a chess game in Unity. What I'm trying to do is have a dictionary which contains each square `(A1, A2, etc)` as a key value and it's value being a `Vector3` object (eg. 0, 0, 10) with the location of square, to which the chess piece would move. Here's my code at the moment.

```
IDictionary<string, Vector3> locations = new Dictionary<string, Vector3>()
{
    {"A1", Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)},
    {"A2", Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)}
};
```

When I run it, Unity's console says the following:

> Expression denotes a type, where a variable, value or method
>   group was expected

Does anyone know how to fix it / a better way to code it?

Comment: `Vector3` is not a method, it's a `struct`. You cannot call a `struct` like that

Comment: `Vector3` is a struct, it's not a method. You have to put `new` before the name of a struct if you want to create an instance of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new) keyword in front of `Vector3` constructors, so the following should works:

```
IDictionary<string, Vector3> locations = new Dictionary<string, Vector3>()
{
    {"A1", new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)},
    {"A2", new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)}
};
```